# htaccess not working as expected?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this litle php page that im testing htaccess with this code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['opt'])) {
    echo 'your option was '.$_GET['opt'];
}
else {
    echo 'please write something like ?opt=1';
}

?>
```

then im my htaccess file i have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-_\-]+)/?$    page.php?opt=$1    [L]
```

when i try to put in the url something like page/1 it wont work but when i change the htaccess from ^page to ^pages it works... how come?

I want the url to be page/something

tks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-_\-]+)/?$    page.php?opt=$1    [L]
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

So in your case it must be deactivated.

Comment: tks for the answer =) why is it that on other wamp instalation what i had works whithout Options -multiviews? apache versions?

Comment: The one who realized this installation found it more logical certainly. This is not necessarily wrong.